# How to plot based on density

Tags: r, plot, spatial

[image]

I want to do a spatial plot. I did the plot. I used different colors to identify different values. But, i want different shades of one color. Is there any way to plot the same plot using different shades of the same color based on higher to lower values?

```
library(maps)

C <-88
A <- c(6.79,10.64,11.06,11.59,2.46,10.64,3.22,6.79,6.79,
   11.06, 4.82,4.82,6.79,6.79,11.06,3.22,8.12,11.59,
   4.82,10.64,8.12,10.64,8.12,8.12,8.12,10.64,2.46,
   11.59,4.82,3.22,6.79,10.64,8.12,3.22,10.64,6.79,
   2.46,11.06,10.64,2.46,3.22,8.12,11.59,2.46,8.12,
   8.12,11.59,10.64,8.12,11.06,8.12,11.06,2.46,10.64,
   4.82,3.22,4.82,3.22,8.12,3.22,3.22,10.64,10.64,2.46,
   8.12,2.46,11.06,4.82,10.64,11.06,2.46,10.64,2.46,
   10.64,4.82,11.06,11.06,11.06, 11.06,8.12, 10.64,2.46,
   6.79, 3.22, 11.06, 10.64,10.64,8.12)

A.color <- array(NA,C)
for (i in 1:C)  {
  if(A[i] == 10.64) A.color[i]  <- c("red")
  if(A[i] == 11.59) A.color[i] <- c("blue")
  if(A[i] == 4.82)  A.color[i] <- c("green")
  if(A[i] == 8.12)  A.color[i] <- c("purple")
  if(A[i] == 11.06) A.color[i] <- c("magenta")
  if(A[i] == 6.79)  A.color[i] <- c("black")
  if(A[i] == 2.46)  A.color[i] <- c("yellow")
  if(A[i] == 3.22)  A.color[i] <- c("violet")
}

map("county", "ohio", fill = TRUE, col=A.color[],
border=c(0,0),mar=c(0,0,0,0),main="Undertriage")
title("Undertriage plot by region")

legend("bottomright",legend=c("UT-18.12 %","UT-19.75 %", "UT-8.21 %","UT- 13.84 %","UT-18.85 %", "UT-11.56 %", "UT-4.20 %","UT-5.48 %"), 

 fill=c("red","blue","green","purple","magenta","black","yellow","violet"),
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]bty="n", cex=1.0, horiz=F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `rgb()` to generate colors:

```
A.color <- rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha =  (A + 0.5) / (max(A) + 0.5) )

map("county", "ohio", fill = TRUE, col=A.color,
    border=c(0,0),mar=c(0,0,0,0),main="Undertriage")
title("Undertriage plot by region")
```

[image]

```
A.color <- rgb(1.2*max(A) - A, 0, 0, maxColorValue = max(A))

map("county", "ohio", fill = TRUE, col=A.color,
    border=c(0,0),mar=c(0,0,0,0),main="Undertriage")
title("Undertriage plot by region")
```

[image]

Or maybe take a look at `?heat.colors`:

```
A.color <- heat.colors(length(unique(A)))
A.color <- A.color[c(factor(A))]

map("county", "ohio", fill = TRUE, col=A.color,
    border=c(0,0),mar=c(0,0,0,0),main="Undertriage")
title("Undertriage plot by region")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  but i want same color of different degree, which will show deep red for higher density and lighter shades of red as the density decrease. And it will show a bar on the side showing the color distribution.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add the legend here ? @ J.R

Comment: yes, this is not a problem if you supply the data on how the legends are related to `A` so we don't need to do it manually like you did. Then we just sort the legend and colors first.